# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imagebutton, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception in my application. I want to put a previous button in my app. I have 5 elements in my array the button cycles through. How do I make it so when user hits element[0], it will loop back to element[4] and not go to a [-1] causing the exception?

My code is as follows:

```
mPrevButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
mPrevButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
        mIsCheater = false;
        updateQuestion();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of doing this:

```
mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
```

Comment: if((mCurrentIndex -1) >= 0) { mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1)% mQuestionBank.length; }

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple?

```
if (mCurrentIndex > 0)
    mCurrentIndex--;
else
    mCurrentIndex = mQuestionBank.length-1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to increment in this way:

```
mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + mQuestionBank.length - 1)% mQuestionBank.length;
```

Comment: Yep, earlier topicstarter got ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on case when
`mCurrentIndex == 0`, because, following [Java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.17.3) "result of the remainder operation can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive only if the dividend is positive;", so `(mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length == -1 % mQuestionBank.length == -1`

Comment: It's a tricky way, but I'd rather avoid formulas like this, cause it's hard to understand.